# Get the node value from json in powershell

Tags: json, powershell

I have json body in powershell variable and want to get value from it.

Json Body :

```
"value":  [
                  {
                      "id":  1,
                      "scope":  "3e93f9e6-f427-48e1-b37b-994d196e1121",
                      "name":  "Default",
                      "isHosted":  false,
                      "poolType":  "automation",
                      "size":  3
                  },
                  {
                      "id":  2,
                      "scope":  "3e93f9e6-f427-48e1-b37b-994d196e1121",
                      "name":  "Hosted",
                      "isHosted":  true,
                      "poolType":  "automation",
                      "size":  10
                  },
                  {
                      "id":  4,
                      "scope":  "3e93f9e6-f427-48e1-b37b-994d196e1121",
                      "name":  "Hosted VS2017",
                      "isHosted":  true,
                      "poolType":  "automation",
                      "size":  10
                  }]
```

I want to get the id value where name=Hosted VS2017 i.e 4

powershell :

```
Write-Host "json body:" $projects
$id = $projects.value | where { $_.name -eq "Hosted VS2017" }
Write-Host "id :" $id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your JSON into a powershell object before you can work with it:

```
$projects = $projects | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Then you can access its members:

```
#requires -Version 3

$projects.value | ? name -eq 'Hosted VS2017'
```

Comment: ConvertFrom-Json : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Depth'.

Comment: @rAJ Check now :)

Comment: Cool. It works
$id = $projects.value | ? name -eq 'Hosted VS2017'
Write-Host "Agent Pool Id :" $id.id